# Running Custom Terminal Command from PHP

Tags: php, shell, exec

The question is about running external commands from PHP. Please find my code below.

```
    $htmlcontent=$_POST['source'];
    echo $htmlcontent;
    if(!isset($htmlcontent)){die('No HTML Cannot Proceed');}
    $sourcefile='sourcefile.html';

    $htmlfile=fopen($sourcefile,'w') or die('Open Failed');

    fwrite($htmlfile,$htmlcontent);
    fclose($htmlfile);

    if(!file_exists($sourcefile)){die('File Creation failed');}

    $command="CutyCapt --html=sourcefile.html --out=trials.png";

    echo 'Executing'.shell_exec($command);
```

I am trying to generate snapshots of a provided source HTML, using CutyCapt. My CutyCapt is running fine from commandline, and it generates snapshots also. But When i run it like i written in the code there is nothing happening.

I tried executing normal commands like `ls` from it. Those are working from webserver also. So confused with this, can any one suggest me some thing?

Where i might had gone wrong? I have CutyCapt in bin, ready to be executed at terminal.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with PHP 5.3.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Does the webserver have execute permissions on CutyCapt, and is that app in the shell's path? Does it also have write permissions to work with trials.png? To get around the path issue, use an absolute path: `/usr/bin/CutyCapt ...`

Comment: I tried setting 0777 to that folder. Still no change.

Comment: I have already given the www-data(WebServer) user the privileges. But the problem exists with some of commands. Like 'ls, ps' works fine, but 'la' dont.. I dont know why its not working

Comment: Check php.ini to make sure you're allowed to run commands

Answer (score 0):

use system() or exec()  and passthru
look it up on php.net

Comment: and with something like exec(command, $data); var_dump($data);

Comment: hmm got a few other suggestions maybe you need to chmod the php file or the executable(777)?

Comment: I tried all these before posting here. Any way now i run it using some kind of a client-server mechanism. Thanks